# my xml wont load my when i try my aplication on a mobile phone

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder

I have an issue with my as3 project: I'm doing a game for mobile, when I test it in the mobile the game loads but my images and arrays (that I store in XML) doesn't load. They loads however when I run it in my computer

How is that possible? Can someone give me an advice?

My code loads an XML with the Pictures and the arrays to the game

Comment: Give some "meat" into your question:) paste the code taht you are using to load XML, tell us the location of the XML etc.

Comment: this is how i load the xml, works perfectly in windows but as soon as o made it as mobile all it didnt load xml, i get error:IO Error: Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/assets/flag.xml

Comment: my xml is build like this:public function loadXML():void
  {//this function loads the xml
   _xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
   _xmlLoader.load( new URLRequest(XML_PATH));
   _xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoaded);
   _xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
  }

Comment: private const XML_PATH:String =   "../assets/flag.xml"; do i need Another kind of link?

Comment: Maybe ../ is not where you think it is. you are saying that error states: "app:/assets/flag.xml" - is it correct path?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the files that you are needed (even the ones in the xml) is included.
These can be seen in the setting before publishing.

Comment: i had included all folders in settings Before publishing the game runs with out the assets in the xml

Comment: It's better to include all files in just a single folder(root). Are using URLRequest for external data? You must ensure that you are trying to access the correct path.